# Kafka : could not find or load main class installation Windows

Tags: java, windows, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I am trying to install Apache Kafka on my computer. I downloaded newest version 2.12-2.0.0. I want to run it on Windows, after typing ".\zookeeper-server-start.bat ../../config/zookeeper.properties" inside \bin\windows directory I am receiving:

Error: Could not find or load main class Files\Java\jdk-10.0.1\lib;C:\Program
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Files\Java\jdk-10/0/1\lib;C:\Program

Java works on my computer properly java -version:

openjdk version "10.0.1" 2018-04-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 10.0.1+10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 10.0.1+10, mixed mode)

JDK is located inside C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.1
I have variables:

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.1
JDK_HOME=%JAVA_HOME%
JRE_HOME=%JAVA_HOME%\jre
PATH: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.1\bin 
CLASSPATH: %JAVA_HOME%\lib;%JAVA_HOME%\jre\
```

Comment: I had similar issues under windows and solved by using `git bash` and the `.sh` version of the executables of kafka and zookeeper

Answer (score 8):

Your JAVA_HOME (and full Kafka path) cannot contain spaces (i believe there's an open JIRA for fixing this)

Try `C:\PROGRA~1\Java\jdk-10.0.1`, and if that doesn't work, install Java to somewhere like `C:\jdk-X.Y.Z\`, <strike>as lower versions of Kafka don't support Java 10</strike>

In general, though, the recommendation is to use WSL2 (or Docker), not CMD/Powershell

https://www.confluent.io/blog/set-up-and-run-kafka-on-windows-linux-wsl-2/

Comment: I was using the 2.6.0 version and had the JAVA_HOME containing spaces as well, but what solved the issue for me was not JAVA_HOME but rather moving *apache kafka binaries* so the path doesn't contain spaces.

Comment: yeap, my folder have some space on. then I put underline on the name instead of space. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Set the below configurations in your **kafka-run-class.bat** and try to start the server

SET "JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.1"

set "CLASSPATH=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.1\lib;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.1\lib\tools.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.1\lib\slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar"

Comment: kafka-run-class needs kafka libraries on the classpath as well

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue, and I solved it by renaming the folder in which I store Kafka to new name has no space.
But for the case of this post we can not rename folder Program Files then solution is moving Kafka to another folder and make sure the path to this folder does not has space.

Comment: As answered in my post, Using `PROGRA~1` is how to "fix" the program files path having spaces

Answer (score 0):

I know, I am late into this query. But 2 cents of mine which I identified.

Please make sure that there should not be any space with your KAFKA_HOME and JAVA_HOME paths. For me, I had the Kafka installation as `c:\software\Apache Kafka 3.1\kafka-src`

And I thought that it should work as the Kafka installation path (starting from Kafka-src) did not have any space but I was wrong. Please make sure the entire Kafka Installation path (starting from `c:`) should not have any spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Just place kafka folder outside the Program Files. Place them in C directory and start again to see the magic.
[image]

Comment: You will need to edit your answer and add the code that you have written or used. Screenshots or text are less helpful than pasted text.